# Is there a function in oracle sql to define start date and end date of a week from column

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5, oracle-apex-5.1

Im getting startdate and end date in two line items when i run below code. How can i get both together like - Dec 02 - Dec 08

````
select to_char(trunc(TRANSITION_TIME, 'IW'),'Mon DD') startweek, to_char(trunc(TRANSITION_TIME, 'IW')+7,'Mon DD') endweek, count(*)  from bats
group by trunc(TRANSITION_TIME, 'IW') ```
````

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer - i need to include || symbol in between both the columns